# MySQL PDO - check if INSERT IGNORE INTO was inserted

Tags: mysql, pdo

How I can check if query `INSERT IGNORE INTO` was correctly inserted to database ?

Now I checked it in that way:

```
$sql = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INGORE INTO ...");
if ( $sql->execute() )
{
    $last_id = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

But execute() always return `TRUE` when $last_id sometimes return `0` so I think my script is not good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[PDO::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) will return the number of rows affected by an `INSERT` query.

So you can check

```
if ( $sql->execute() && $sql->rowCount() > 0 ) {
    // do something
}
```